# NFC and ISO 14443 : security?

Tags: authentication, nfc

I'm trying to understand if the [ISO 14443](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_14443) guarantees any degree of security for an NFC transaction. I can't access the documentation because it is not free, but I see devices (like MIFARE DESFire or what) claiming they respect the standard.

When I see summaries of the content of the standard, I don't see any information in terms of security, authentication, or what.

Does somebody know if there is something to know about?
Is the security of these devices only ensured by the constructors?

Comment: ISO14443 is just a link protocol like Ethernet, as far as I know it does not provide any security by itself, it's up to the different vendors to implement their own on top of that.

Answer (score 3):

ISO14443 is just a link protocol like Ethernet, as far as I know it does not provide any security by itself, it's up to the different vendors to implement their own on top of that.